# invocation of base class overridden method from super class constructor

Tags: java, inheritance

Given the following block of code i would like to understand why and how, emphasis on **how**, the method print in Subclass is invoked:

```
class Super {

    Super() {

        // what happens so that Sub's method print() is invoked
        print();
    }

    public void print() {

        System.out.println("in super");
    }
}

class Sub extends Super {

    Sub() {

        super();
    }

    public void print() {

        System.out.println("in sub");
    }
}

public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Super s = new Sub(); // "in sub".. not so much expected

        s.print(); // "in sub".. as expected
    }
}
```

My understanding is that during compile time, classes will get V-table pointer`vtblPtr`associated with methods 'belonging' to a class.
Class `Super` should therefore have reference to it's own implementation of method `print()`.

How come the method `print()` in `Sub` is invoked in constructor of `Super`? What really happens here ?

Comment: I think you're confusing C++ and Java: there is no concept of a vtblPtr in Java.

Comment: I was under the impression that java uses virtual tables to implement polymorphism ?

Comment: it's a concept that doesn't exist. Each JVM is free to come up with its own way. And it does. The HotSpot compiler will detect whether there are any subclasses loaded, or whether the code is invoked with a subclass or not, and then decide whether to do a virtual dispatch, a direct dispatch, or even an inlining of the code. It's not possible to tell from the Java code or bytecode how it's actually done at a certain point in time.

Comment: Ok,thx. Although i am quite certain that i have read somewhere that every class in java have associated vtable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what `Super` class looks like for the JVM (actually, that is the human-readable version obtained by `javap -c Super`)

```
class Super {
  Super();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: aload_0       
       5: invokevirtual #2                  // Method print:()V
       8: return        

  public void print();
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #3                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: ldc           #4                  // String in super
       5: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
       8: return        
}
```

as you can see, the `print` inside `Super` contructor was not resolved at compile time to `Super::print`. A virtual call means that it is resolved at runtime, with respect to class of `this`.

Comment: This might be useful resource to add: http://cs.au.dk/~mis/dOvs/jvmspec/ref--35.html

Answer (score 2):

> My understanding is that during compile time, classes will get V-table pointervtblPtrassociated with methods 'belonging' to a class. Class Super should therefore have reference to it's own implementation of method print().

You have a fundamental misunderstanding about virtual methods and overriding.  In Java, every non-`static`, non-`private` method is virtual.  Every virtual (normal) invocation of a virtual method, from anywhere, will invoke the version associated with the class *of the object on which the method is invoked*.  That version might or might not be inherited, and might or might not override a superclass's method.

That a virtual method invocation is performed implicitly or explicitly on `this` in no way changes any of that.  In particular, the actual class of the object being initialized is visible to every constructor, and provides the context for all their method invocations.  In fact, this is why it's rarely a good idea for a constructor to invoke a virtual method provided by its own class.  Superclass constructors run before subclass constructors, so if a superclass constructor invokes a method that happens to be overridden by a subclass, then that method will run before the object is fully initialized in the way that method may assume.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.